# mysql - collapsing or overlaying multiple rows with null values in some fields

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table:

```
CREATE TABLE `t` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `priority` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `val1` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `val2` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `val3` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=4 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
INSERT INTO `t` VALUES (1,'tj',1,'Set-1',NULL,NULL),(2,'tj',5,'Z-invalid','Set-2',NULL),(3,'tj',10,'a-invalid','Z-invalid','Set-3');
```

Here's what the data looks like:

```
mysql> select * from t;
+----+------+----------+-----------+-----------+-------+
| id | user | priority | val1      | val2      | val3  |
+----+------+----------+-----------+-----------+-------+
|  1 | tj   |        1 | Set-1     | NULL      | NULL  |
|  2 | tj   |        5 | Z-invalid | Set-2     | NULL  |
|  3 | tj   |       10 | a-invalid | Z-invalid | Set-3 |
+----+------+----------+-----------+-----------+-------+
```

What I'd like to do is sort by priority, and collapse, or overlay the data.  If the value in a column is NULL, then get the value from the next highest priority column.  If a field is not null, then stop there.

It should end up looking like this:

```
+------+-----------+-----------+-------+
| user | val1      | val2      | val3  |
+------+-----------+-----------+-------+
| tj   | Set-1     | Set-2     | Set-3 |
+------+-----------+-----------+-------+
```

If I were looking to get just one field, it'd be easy - I'd just do

```
SELECT val1 FROM t WHERE user='tj' AND val1 IS NOT NULL ORDER BY priority ASC LIMIT 1;
```

But the table where I'm actually looking to implement this idea has some 30 columns, and I don't want to do 30 different selects.  And I can't use MAX, becuase it's the priority that determines which value to display for each column, not the MAX of the value of the column itself.

Is there some sort of aggregation option that I'm missing here?

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit of a hack and will require examining every row so performance will be horrible if your table is huge, but you can do something like:

```
set @val1 = NULL;
set @val2 = NULL;
set @val3 = NULL;

select @val1 AS val1, @val2 AS val2, @val3 AS val3
from
(
  select @val1 := COALESCE(@val1, val1) AS val1, 
         @val2 := COALESCE(@val2, val2) AS val2, 
         @val3 := COALESCE(@val3, val3) AS val3
  from t 
  order by priority asc
) x
limit 1
```

[SQL Fiddle demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f19fc/17)

Comment: Yes, unfortunately, the table is huge....and the query would get really convoluted with the large number of columns.  That's why I was hoping for something more generic that would work for n-columns.

Comment: Well, the problem is coming from the way the data is stored; if it were in rows, the query would be trivial.

Comment: I wonder how this would work if it required a GROUP BY; e.g, assuming there were more than one user (more than one user besides 'tj')